# AFNetworking with no serialization

Tags: ios, serialization, afnetworking-2

Good day everyone! I've been using AFNetworking 2.0 for a quite a while and because input was always of https with json - never had any problem. Yet now we have a custom written on C server which works only with HTTP and sends encrypted raw byte data.

As far as I understand it's necessary to use some sort of serializer , but i can choose only from: AFHTTPResponseSerializer/AFJSONResponseSerializer/AFXMLParserResponseSerializer/AFXMLDocumentResponseSerializer/AFPropertyListResponseSerializer  and none of them seems to fit.
What's the best solution?
As result i need decrypted NSData which i can parse byte by byte.

Comment: Probably you can write your own Request, Response Serializer for that - it's easy to extend.

Comment: That's what i thought too... but still - cannot believe that no one ever encountered same task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the possibilities of encryption rule out a standard ResponseSerializer. Some of the encryption properties include algorithm, key, key size, mode, possible iv and padding.

The solution is to decrypt the received data in a separate step.

In order to decrypt the data you need to know the algorithm, it's parameters and the encryption key. It is also possible that additional encryption information is added to the encrypted data such as an iv, KDF reputation count, etc. You need to obtain this information from the server developers.

Comment: Emm, as far as I didn'n't understand the tutorial on GitHub - It says that afnetwroking handles all the encryption decryption problems automatically - once i attached key and cert? Maybe you could point me somewhere to read about SSL, because there isn't anything here or on ray or at AF page?

Comment: Made this suggestion because you can pin certificate and set security policy. So i need somehow to decrypt additionally incoming packages?

Comment: The https encryption is transparent, it is not handles in AFNetworking, it is handles prior to AFNetworking. The data may be additionally encrypted, that is what the answer is about. I made this assumption based on the question stating that https was already being used. Please add more information to the question.

Comment: Sorry - i spotted it very late. I am trying to switch from http to https. So basically ssl handshake is handled by afnetworking and synchronous encryption is what i and server dealed before.